# Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0)

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview, nativescript

I'm new to Android development. I chose NativeScript for this purpose.

In a scenario I needed to use RadListView, so I added its plugin to my app. But when I try to run the app, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
  https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.jar
```

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/28.0.0/recyclerview-v7-28.0.0.jar returns a 404 Error.

**How to reproduce:**

```
> tns create my-app --template tns-template-hello-world
> cd my-app
> tns run android
> tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
> tns run android
```

First `run` is OK, second one is not.

Closest page to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470525/could-not-find-recyclerview-v7-jar-com-android-supportrecyclerview-v727-1-1). But he could solve his problem by upgrading gradle. I have already its latest release.

My **build.gradle (root)**:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My **build.gradle (app)**:

```
/*
*   Script builds apk in release or debug mode
*   To run:
*           gradle assembleRelease -Prelease (release mode)
*           gradle assembleDebug (debug mode -> default)
*   Options:
*           -Prelease  //this flag will run build in release mode
*           -PksPath=[path_to_keystore_file]
*           -PksPassword=[password_for_keystore_file]
*           -Palias=[alias_to_use_from_keystore_file]
*           -Ppassword=[password_for_alias]
*
*           -PtargetSdk=[target_sdk]
*           -PbuildToolsVersion=[build_tools_version]
*           -PsupportVersion=[support_version]
*           -PcompileSdk=[compile_sdk_version]
*/

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

def onlyX86 = project.hasProperty("onlyX86")
if (onlyX86) {
    println "OnlyX86 build triggered."
}

//common
def BUILD_TOOLS_PATH = "$rootDir/build-tools"
def PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH = System.getenv("TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH")
def TYPINGS_PATH = "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/typings"
if (PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH != null) {
    TYPINGS_PATH = PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH
}

def USER_PROJECT_ROOT = "$rootDir/../.."
def PLATFORMS_ANDROID = "platforms/android"
def PACKAGE_JSON = "package.json"

//static binding generator
def SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES = "sbg-java-dependencies.txt"
def SBG_INPUT_FILE = "sbg-input-file.txt"
def SBG_OUTPUT_FILE = "sbg-output-file.txt"
def SBG_JS_PARSED_FILES = "sbg-js-parsed-files.txt"
def SBG_BINDINGS_NAME = "sbg-bindings.txt"
def SBG_INTERFACE_NAMES = "sbg-interface-names.txt"
def INPUT_JS_DIR = "$projectDir/src/main/assets/app"
def OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR = "$projectDir/src/main/java"

//metadata generator
def MDG_OUTPUT_DIR = "mdg-output-dir.txt"
def MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES = "mdg-java-dependencies.txt"
def METADATA_OUT_PATH = "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"

// paths to jar libraries
def pluginsJarLibraries = new LinkedList<String>()
def allJarLibraries = new LinkedList<String>()

// the build script will not work with previous versions of the CLI (3.1 or earlier)
def dependenciesJson = file("$rootDir/dependencies.json")
if (!dependenciesJson.exists()) {
    throw new BuildCancelledException("""
'dependencies.json' file not found. Check whether the NativeScript CLI has prepared the project beforehand,
and that your NativeScript version is 3.3, or a more recent one. To build an android project with the current
version of the {N} CLI install a previous version of the runtime package - 'tns platform add android@3.2'.
""")
}

project.ext.extractedDependenciesDir = "${project.buildDir}/exploded-dependencies"
def nativescriptDependencies = new JsonSlurper().parseText(dependenciesJson.text)

def computeCompileSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("compileSdk") ? compileSdk : 28 }
def computeTargetSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("targetSdk") ? targetSdk : 28 }
def computeBuildToolsVersion = { ->
    project.hasProperty("buildToolsVersion") ? buildToolsVersion : "28.0.3"
}

project.ext.selectedBuildType = project.hasProperty("release") ? "release" : "debug"
project.ext.appResourcesPath = ""

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATIONS ///////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

def getAppResourcesPath = { ->
    def relativePathToApp = "app"
    def relativePathToAppResources
    def absolutePathToAppResources
    def nsConfigFile = file("$USER_PROJECT_ROOT/nsconfig.json")
    def nsConfig

    if (nsConfigFile.exists()) {
        nsConfig = new JsonSlurper().parseText(nsConfigFile.getText("UTF-8"))
    }

    if(nsConfig != null && nsConfig.appPath != null){
        relativePathToApp = nsConfig.appPath
    }

    if(nsConfig != null && nsConfig.appResourcesPath != null ) {
        relativePathToAppResources = nsConfig.appResourcesPath
    } else {
        relativePathToAppResources  = "$relativePathToApp/App_Resources"
    }

    absolutePathToAppResources = java.nio.file.Paths.get(USER_PROJECT_ROOT).resolve(relativePathToAppResources).toAbsolutePath()

    project.ext.appResourcesPath = absolutePathToAppResources

    return absolutePathToAppResources
}

def applyBeforePluginGradleConfiguration = { ->
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def pathToBeforePluginGradle = "$appResourcesPath/Android/before-plugins.gradle"
    def beforePluginGradle = file(pathToBeforePluginGradle)
    if (beforePluginGradle.exists()) {
        println "\t + applying user-defined configuration from ${beforePluginGradle}"
        apply from: pathToBeforePluginGradle
    }
}

def applyAppGradleConfiguration = { ->
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def pathToAppGradle = "$appResourcesPath/Android/app.gradle"
    def appGradle = file(pathToAppGradle)
    if (appGradle.exists()) {
        println "\t + applying user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}"
        apply from: pathToAppGradle
    } else {
        println "\t + couldn't load user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}. File doesn't exist."
    }
}

def applyPluginGradleConfigurations = { ->
    nativescriptDependencies.each {dep ->
        def includeGradlePath = "$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID/include.gradle"
        if(file(includeGradlePath).exists()) {
            apply from: includeGradlePath
        }
    }
}

def getAppIdentifier = { packageJsonMap ->
    def appIdentifier = "";
    if (packageJsonMap && packageJsonMap.nativescript) {
        appIdentifier = packageJsonMap.nativescript.id;
        if (!(appIdentifier instanceof String)) {
            appIdentifier = appIdentifier.android;
        }
    }

    return appIdentifier;
}

def setAppIdentifier = { ->
    println "\t + setting applicationId";
    File packageJsonFile = new File("$rootDir/../../package.json");

    if (packageJsonFile.exists()) {
        def content = packageJsonFile.getText("UTF-8");
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
        def packageJsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(content);
        def appIdentifier = getAppIdentifier(packageJsonMap);

        if (appIdentifier) {
            project.ext.nsApplicationIdentifier = appIdentifier;
            android.defaultConfig.applicationId = appIdentifier;
        }
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion computeCompileSdkVersion()
    buildToolsVersion computeBuildToolsVersion()

    defaultConfig {
        def manifest = new XmlSlurper().parse(file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile))
        def minSdkVer = manifest."uses-sdk"."@android:minSdkVersion".text() ?: 17
        minSdkVersion minSdkVer
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
        ndk {
            if (onlyX86) {
                abiFilters 'x86'
            } else {
                abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'//, 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            jumboMode = true
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir "$projectDir/libs/jni"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("release")) {
                if (project.hasProperty("ksPath") &&
                        project.hasProperty("ksPassword") &&
                        project.hasProperty("alias") &&
                        project.hasProperty("password")) {

                    storeFile file(ksPath)
                    storePassword ksPassword
                    keyAlias alias
                    keyPassword password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    setAppIdentifier()
    applyBeforePluginGradleConfiguration()
    applyPluginGradleConfigurations()
    applyAppGradleConfiguration()
}

def externalRuntimeExists = !findProject(':runtime').is(null)

repositories {
    // used for local *.AAR files
    def pluginDependencies = nativescriptDependencies.collect {
        "$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"
    }

    // some plugins may have their android dependencies in a /libs subdirectory
    pluginDependencies.addAll(nativescriptDependencies.collect {
        "$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID/libs"
    })

    if (!externalRuntimeExists) {
        pluginDependencies.add("libs/runtime-libs")
    }

    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def localAppResourcesLibraries = "$appResourcesPath/Android/libs"

    pluginDependencies.add(localAppResourcesLibraries)

    if (pluginDependencies.size() > 0) {
        flatDir {
            dirs pluginDependencies
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    def supportVer = "28.0.0"
    if (project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
        supportVer = supportVersion
    }

    println "Using support library version $supportVer"

    implementation "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportVer"

    def sbgProjectExists = !findProject(':static-binding-generator').is(null)
    if (sbgProjectExists) {
        compileOnly project(':static-binding-generator')
    }
    def mdgProjectExists = !findProject(':android-metadata-generator').is(null)
    if (mdgProjectExists) {
        compileOnly project(':android-metadata-generator')
    }
    def dtsgProjectExists = !findProject(':dts-generator').is(null)
    if (dtsgProjectExists) {
        compileOnly project(':dts-generator')
    }

    def useV8Symbols = nativescriptDependencies.any {
        def packageJsonPath = file("$rootDir/${it.directory}/$PACKAGE_JSON")
        def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(packageJsonPath.text)
        return packageJson.nativescript.useV8Symbols
    }
    if (!externalRuntimeExists) {
        def runtime = "nativescript-optimized-with-inspector"

        if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.toLowerCase().contains('release') }) {
            runtime = "nativescript-optimized"
        }

        if (useV8Symbols) {
            runtime = "nativescript-regular"
        }

        println "\t + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: $runtime"
        project.dependencies.add("implementation", [name: runtime, ext: "aar"])
    } else {
        implementation project(path: ':runtime', configuration: 'default')
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATION PHASE //////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task addDependenciesFromNativeScriptPlugins {
    nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
        def aarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"), include: ["**/*.aar"])
        aarFiles.each { aarFile ->
            def length = aarFile.name.length() - 4
            def fileName = aarFile.name[0..<length]
            println "\t + adding aar plugin dependency: " + aarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            project.dependencies.add("implementation", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
        }

        def jarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("$rootDir/${dep.directory}/$PLATFORMS_ANDROID"), include: ["**/*.jar"])
        jarFiles.each { jarFile ->
            def jarFileAbsolutePath = jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            println "\t + adding jar plugin dependency: $jarFileAbsolutePath"
            pluginsJarLibraries.add(jarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        project.dependencies.add("implementation", jarFiles)
    }
}

task addDependenciesFromAppResourcesLibraries {
    def appResourcesPath = getAppResourcesPath()
    def appResourcesLibraries = file("$appResourcesPath/Android/libs")
    if (appResourcesLibraries.exists()) {
        def aarFiles = fileTree(dir: appResourcesLibraries, include: ["**/*.aar"])
        aarFiles.each { aarFile ->
            def length = aarFile.name.length() - 4
            def fileName = aarFile.name[0..<length]
            println "\t + adding aar library dependency: " + aarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            project.dependencies.add("implementation", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
        }

        def jarFiles = fileTree(dir: appResourcesLibraries, include: ["**/*.jar"])
        jarFiles.each { jarFile ->
            def jarFileAbsolutePath = jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            println "\t + adding jar plugin dependency: $jarFileAbsolutePath"
            pluginsJarLibraries.add(jarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        project.dependencies.add("implementation", jarFiles)
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded({ org.gradle.api.DefaultTask currentTask ->
    if (currentTask =~ /generate.+BuildConfig/) {
        currentTask.finalizedBy(extractAllJars)
        extractAllJars.finalizedBy(collectAllJars)
    }
    if (currentTask =~ /compile.+JavaWithJavac/) {
        currentTask.dependsOn(runSbg)
        currentTask.finalizedBy(ensureMetadataOutDir)
        ensureMetadataOutDir.finalizedBy(buildMetadata)
    }
    if (currentTask =~ /assemble.*Debug/ || currentTask =~ /assemble.*Release/) {
        currentTask.finalizedBy("validateAppIdMatch")
    }
})

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// EXECUTUION PHASE /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task runSbg(type: JavaExec) {
    inputs.dir(INPUT_JS_DIR)

    workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
    main "-jar"
    args "static-binding-generator.jar"

    doFirst {
        new File("$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen").deleteDir();
    }
}

task ensureMetadataOutDir {
    doLast {
        def outputDir = file("$METADATA_OUT_PATH")
        outputDir.mkdirs()
    }
}

def explodeAar(File compileDependency, String outputDir) {
    if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".aar")) {
        java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(compileDependency)
        Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries()
        while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement()
            if (file.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
                def f = new File(outputDir, file.name)
                new File(f.parent).mkdirs()
                InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file)
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f)
                while (is.available() > 0) {
                    fos.write(is.read())
                }
                fos.close()
                is.close()
            }
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                continue
            }
        }
        jar.close()
    } else if (compileDependency.name.endsWith(".jar")) {
        copy {
            from compileDependency.absolutePath
            into outputDir
        }
    }
}

task extractAllJars {
    outputs.dir extractedDependenciesDir

    doLast {
        def buildType = project.selectedBuildType == "release" ? "Release" : "Debug"
        def iter = []
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+)${buildType}CompileClasspath\$")
        configurations.all{ config ->
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(config.name)
            if (matcher.find() || config.name == "${buildType.toLowerCase()}CompileClasspath") {
                config.resolve().each {
                    if (!iter.contains(it)) {
                        iter.push(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        def dependencyCounter = 0
        iter.each {
            def nextDependency = it
            def outputDir = java.nio.file.Paths.get(extractedDependenciesDir, "" + dependencyCounter).normalize().toString()
            explodeAar(nextDependency, outputDir)
            dependencyCounter++
        }
    }
}

task collectAllJars {
    description "gathers all paths to jar dependencies before building metadata with them"

    def sdkPath = android.sdkDirectory.getAbsolutePath()
    def androidJar = sdkPath + "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

    doFirst {
        def allJarPaths = new LinkedList<String>()
        allJarPaths.add(androidJar)
        allJarPaths.addAll(pluginsJarLibraries)
        def ft = fileTree(dir: extractedDependenciesDir, include: "**/*.jar")
        ft.each { currentJarFile ->
            allJarPaths.add(currentJarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriter { out ->
            allJarPaths.each { out.println it }
        }
        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriter { out ->
            allJarPaths.each {
                if (it.endsWith(".jar")) {
                    out.println it
                }
            }
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INPUT_FILE").withWriter { out ->
            out.println INPUT_JS_DIR
        }
        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_OUTPUT_FILE").withWriter { out ->
            out.println OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR
        }

        allJarLibraries.addAll(allJarPaths)
    }
}

task buildMetadata(type: JavaExec) {
    description "builds metadata with provided jar dependencies"

    inputs.files("$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES")

    def classesDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/javac"
    inputs.dir(classesDir)

    outputs.files("$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeNodeStream.dat", "$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeStringsStream.dat", "$METADATA_OUT_PATH/treeValueStream.dat")

    doFirst {
        // get compiled classes to pass to metadata generator
        // these need to be called after the classes have compiled
        assert file(classesDir).exists()

        def classesSubDirs = new File(classesDir).listFiles()
        def selectedBuildType = project.ext.selectedBuildType

        def generatedClasses = new LinkedList<String>()
        for (File subDir : classesSubDirs) {
            if (subDir.getName().equals(selectedBuildType)) {
                generatedClasses.add(subDir.getAbsolutePath())
            }
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_OUTPUT_DIR").withWriter { out ->
            out.println "$METADATA_OUT_PATH"
        }

        new File("$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES").withWriterAppend { out ->
            generatedClasses.each { out.println it }
        }

        workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"
        main "-jar"

        args "android-metadata-generator.jar"
    }
}

task generateTypescriptDefinitions(type: JavaExec) {
    def paramz = new ArrayList<String>()
    def includeDirs = ["com.android.support", "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion]

    doFirst {
        delete "$TYPINGS_PATH"

        workingDir "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH"

        main "-jar"

        paramz.add("dts-generator.jar")
        paramz.add("-input")

        for (String jarPath : allJarLibraries) {
            // don't generate typings for runtime jars and classes
            if (shouldIncludeDirForTypings(jarPath, includeDirs)) {
                paramz.add(jarPath)
            }
        }

        paramz.add("-output")
        paramz.add("$TYPINGS_PATH")

        new File("$TYPINGS_PATH").mkdirs()

        logger.info("Task generateTypescriptDefinitions: Call dts-generator.jar with arguments: " + paramz.toString().replaceAll(',', ''))
        println "Task generateTypescriptDefinitions: Call dts-generator.jar with arguments: " + paramz.toString().replaceAll(',', '')
        args paramz.toArray()
    }
}

generateTypescriptDefinitions.onlyIf {
    (project.hasProperty("generateTypings") && Boolean.parseBoolean(project.generateTypings)) || PASSED_TYPINGS_PATH != null
}

collectAllJars.finalizedBy(generateTypescriptDefinitions)

static def shouldIncludeDirForTypings(path, includeDirs) {
    for (String p : includeDirs) {
        if (path.indexOf(p) > -1) {
            return true
        }
    }

    return false
}

task copyTypings {
    doLast {
        println "Copied generated typings to application root level. Make sure to import android.d.ts in reference.d.ts"

        copy {
            from "$TYPINGS_PATH"
            into "$USER_PROJECT_ROOT"
        }
    }
}

copyTypings.onlyIf { generateTypescriptDefinitions.didWork }
generateTypescriptDefinitions.finalizedBy(copyTypings)

task validateAppIdMatch {
    doLast {
        def lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator")

        if (project.hasProperty("nsApplicationIdentifier") && !project.hasProperty("release")) {
            if(project.nsApplicationIdentifier != android.defaultConfig.applicationId) {
                def errorMessage = "${lineSeparator}WARNING: The Application identifier is different from the one inside \"package.json\" file.$lineSeparator" +
                    "NativeScript CLI might not work properly.$lineSeparator" +
                    "Remove applicationId from app.gradle and update the \"nativescript.id\" in package.json.$lineSeparator" +
                    "Actual: ${android.defaultConfig.applicationId}$lineSeparator" +
                    "Expected(from \"package.json\"): ${project.nsApplicationIdentifier}$lineSeparator";

                logger.error(errorMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// OPTIONAL TASKS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////// custom clean ///////////
task cleanSbg(type: Delete) {
    delete "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JS_PARSED_FILES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INTERFACE_NAMES",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_BINDINGS_NAME",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_INPUT_FILE",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$SBG_OUTPUT_FILE",
            "$OUTPUT_JAVA_DIR/com/tns/gen"
}

task cleanMdg(type: Delete) {
    delete "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_OUTPUT_DIR",
            "$BUILD_TOOLS_PATH/$MDG_JAVA_DEPENDENCIES",
            "$METADATA_OUT_PATH"
}

cleanSbg.dependsOn(cleanMdg)
clean.dependsOn(cleanSbg)
```

My **package.json (root)**:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.nativescriptrecyclerview",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^5.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.18.0"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

**Android SDK Tools** from Android Studio:

[image: Installed Android SDK Tools]

**Edit:** Unfortunately I can't confirm whether further answers works, or even respond to comments, since I'm not using NativeScript or other gradle-related projects anymore. But feel free to add your answers or comments; it might help others.

Comment: please share your build.gradle

Comment: @Radesh Please see my build.grade.

Comment: other build.gradle(app module)

Comment: @Radesh Please see my build.gradle from app directory.

Comment: @MojtabaJavan Are you trying to integrate NativeScript with any existing native android app?

Comment: @Manoj No. I created a NativeScript project from scratch.

Comment: In that case which `build.gradle` you are referring, you wouldn't have one in your project and you should not touch the ones those are auto generated within platforms folder. Let's know what you have in your `package.json`

Comment: [Here's the google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) about this problem.

Comment: @Manoj I didn't create any of those gradle files. I tried to solve the problem by editing those files though, but I undid when changes didn't work. Please see my package,json.

Comment: You had mentioned that you added RadListView plugin to your app but I don't see that in your package.json?

Comment: @OiciTrap So, that's about Google servers or something? Is there anything I can do, another repository perhaps?

Comment: @Manoj Sorry, I removed that plugin to continue other parts of my work. Please let me know if you need me to add it again.

Comment: @MojtabaJavan No that I know, in my case it was working fine in Friday and then yesterday I was having this problem too, it seems some libraries used during the compilation are missing.

Comment: I use RadListView day to day and at least I didn't hit such issues so far. So if you have a sample repo, I can take a look.

Comment: In your SDK manager make sure that you have  Android SDK 28, Android Build Tools (28.0.3) and that Google Support repository is updated to the latest published version.

Comment: @NickIliev I have Android SDK Platform with API Level 28. Please see my screenshot from Android SDK Tools. Is there anything missing?

Comment: i have this problem too, is it solved?

Comment: @SeyedAliRoshan Unfortunately not. I just checked it again. The problem persists. I decided to switch to NativeScript-Vue.

Answer (score 1):

In build.gradle this is the new implementation

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't confirm that your solution works, since I'm not using NativeScript or other gradle-related projects anymore. Hope it helps other users. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem from Google's Maven Repository.
Some libraries just disappears 
[Here's](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120759347) the issue on the Google Issue Tracker.

Comment: It seems so as OiciTrap mentioned in the comments, since that issue is just opened yesterday and lots of developers had a similar problem. Hope that would be the case.

Answer (score -2):

Migrate your project to AndroidX using this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

Add below dependency in you app module gradle file

`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'`

Comment: Thanks. Would you please explain why I need to migrate?

Comment: No a valid solution as in NativeScript the migration to AndroidX is not supported yet (in development)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782435/android-design-support-library-for-api-28-p-not-working

Hope this will help